# Shared 'directories' using closure tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, hierarchy

As part of an application I'm working on, users need to be able to store files in directories, and share certain directories for collaboration.

After doing some initial research, I decided to implement a closure table for storing the directory structure (files are stored separately).

Now, I'm looking to implement shared directories, akin to sharing in Dropbox, where each user has their own root-level directory which can't be shared and only children directories can be shared.

I'm wondering how I could go about implementing this?

I used the following repo as a reference for implementing the [closure tree](https://github.com/developerworks/hierarchy-data-closure-table).